# Hibernate, when I make the id column auto increasement with error for sql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I used Hibernate 5 to do ORM in Spring.

My tables are:

```
public class Match {

    @Id
    @Column(name="match_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private ArrayList<String> players;
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy="match")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="match")
    private List<Game> games;
    ...
} 

public class Game {

    @Id
    @Column(name="game_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String person1;
    private String person2;
    private String winner;
    private int score1;
    private int score2;
    private int game_number;

    @Column(name="match_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Match match;
}
```

The relation between two tables is one Match contain many games.

but I get the error for auto increasement, the error is:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (match_id integer not null auto_increment, players tinyblob, primary key (' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Since there is an error and interupt, I do not know how to print the sql.
I do not know just setting id auto increasement have error?
I use the manytoone fellow [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany), my situation is similar to EMPLOYEE (table) and PHONE (table) case.

Comment: have you tried with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.suppose to use a MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT column, you are supposed to use an IDENTITY strategy.

Comment: How are you generating your sql tables?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I tried @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY), but the same situation

Comment: @Shiraaz.M I use the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update in application.properties try to automatical generated table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Match` is a reserved keyword in MySql, and that is what is causing your error. Rename your entity to something different, like `FootballMatch`..